# How to apply filters not only in first but also in continued dialog interactions?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-qna-maker

Given following QnA Maker Knowledge Base:

```
Topic 1 (with meta data: name1 : value1)
 Sub Topic 11 (with no meta data)
 Sub Topic 12 (with meta data: name1 : value1)
```

and dialog:

```
class QnAMakerBaseDialog extends QnAMakerDialog {

    constructor(knowledgebaseId, authkey, host, userProfileAccessor) {
        var noAnswer = ActivityFactory.fromObject(DefaultNoAnswer);
        var filters = [{ name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }];
        super(knowledgebaseId, authkey, host, noAnswer, DefaultThreshold, DefaultCardTitle, DefaultCardNoMatchText,
            DefaultTopN, ActivityFactory.cardNoMatchResponse, filters, QNAMAKER_BASE_DIALOG);
        this.id = QNAMAKER_BASE_DIALOG;
        this.userProfileAccessor = userProfileAccessor;
    }

    async beginDialog(DialogContext, object) {
        this.strintFilters = [{ name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }];
        return await super.beginDialog(DialogContext, object);
    }

    async continueDialog(DialogContext) {
        this.strintFilters = [{ name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }];
        return await super.continueDialog(DialogContext);
    }

}

exports.QnAMakerBaseDialog = QnAMakerBaseDialog;
```

Expected behavior:

Due to an active filter `[{ name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }]` I would expect "Sub Topic 11" (it has no meta data!) NOT to be in the answers returned by QnA Maker.

Actual behavior:

When querying for "Sub topic 11" in first interaction ("beginDialog"), QnA returns "No answers
found" as expected.
However, when querying for "Topic 1", QnA Maker returns

- both "Sub Topic 11" and "Sub Topic 12" (ideally "Sub Topic 11" should not be included in answers), and
- when the dialog is continued ("continueDialog") and the user queries for "Sub Topic 11" as well, "Sub Topic 11" is returned as an answer, even that "Sub Topic 11" doesn't has the required meta data.

It seems QnA Maker only applies filters at the first interaction ("beginDialog") but not on subsequent interactions.

Is there any way to apply filters on all QnA Maker queries?

Comment: Did you mean to put `strictFilters` instead of `strintFilters`?

Comment: I am setting this.strintFilters according to class QnAMakerDialog

Comment: Can you link to any source code or documentation where you're seeing this.strintFilters?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/v4.10.3/libraries/botbuilder-ai/src/qnaMakerDialog.ts Looks like strintFilters has been replaced with strictFilters starting with https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/4.11.0/libraries/botbuilder-ai/src/qnaMakerDialog.ts However, the above code doesn't work with 4.11.0 (or above) even after replacing this.strintFilters with this.strictFilters

Comment: You can see in the source code that you linked to that `strictFilters` is passed to the QnA Maker options by calling [`getValue`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/4.11.0/libraries/botbuilder-ai/src/qnaMakerDialog.ts#L326) on it. Therefore, if you use an array then it won't work because an array has no `getValue` function. You need to use an `ArrayExpression` object the way the QnA Maker dialog's [constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/4.11.0/libraries/botbuilder-ai/src/qnaMakerDialog.ts#L234) does. If that doesn't work, your expected behavior might be wrong

Comment: Did you try that yet?